# Setting up development environment

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, development-environment

I'm a recent CS grad working for a start-up. I've been tasked with adding new features to some software they bought. I've downloaded the software from AWS and have begun trying to get started but I'm having trouble with the front-end, which is built with React and bundled by Webpack.

The download left me with an old version of the front-end and minified files of the new version. I was able to use their source maps to unpack them and get the unbundled files but now I can't figure out how to rebuild it.

The old version is set up to have its dependencies installed and minified by npm. I would like to set up something similar with the new version. I've been able to add all its dependencies to the package.json file but I keep running into errors, mostly stemming from versioning conflicts. What should  I do in this situation? Am I just going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Did they not give you the actual source code which included a package.json? This feels somewhat broad without the actual error descriptions.

Comment: The source code only contained the bundled versions of the front end, so I had to use a tool that used the source maps to get unbundle it. This left me with the files and node_modules folder but not with any package.json.

Comment: I think this question is a bit broad for SO, as it doesn't ask a specific question, with a solvable answer. You should give an example of what kind of error you are getting by "versioning conflicts", something that we could reproduce. Also, a tidbit of advice: talk to your employer about these things. Whoever gave you the work should be able to address the problem you're having. I remember being new, scared to look clueless. Practice open communication with the people above you. You really shouldn't be un-bundling code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry about the broadness of the question, I just wanted to get an opinion from more experienced programmers. I'm definitely nervous about looking clueless but I guess I'll have to get over that considering I am completely clueless on this. I'm going to stop trying to reverse engineer the development environment from the production build and instead try to get in contact with the original developers.

Answer (score 0):

Software might be a vague term to describe what you have in your hands.

It seems from your wording that you have the *source code* of an older version, but the *production build* (`bundle.js, main.chunk.js, etc`) of some newer version, for which you don't have (or potentially own) the source code.

React is very complex itself, it was probably built using Create React App, dealing with the bundled and ejected files is probably worse, and adding the new features without the source code sounds like a nightmare for a CS grad at a startup. This might even potentially be **illegal**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, its a Create React App. The place I work for does own the source code and I'm able to derive the source code using the source maps but after that I'm just confused as hell on how to get it rebuilt and ready for production again.

Comment: Do they have the source code in a repository (ie github, gitlab, some directory) somewhere? It should include a package.json file as well. This is not the version you download on the browser from the network (AWS in your case).

Comment: I can see in their git commits that they used a Github repo. I should probably try to get in contact with the original developers to see about getting the source code.